# Объединить mysql запросы при выборке

Tags: php, mysql, select

Помогите объединить 2 запроса (Это нужно для реализации новостной ленты)

1. **Запрос вывожу аудиозаписи друзей**

   ```
   SELECT
     audios.user_id,
     audios.src,
     audios.title,
     audios.artist
   FROM friends RIGHT OUTER JOIN audios ON friends.friend_id = audios.user_id
   WHERE friends.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY audios.id DESC LIMIT 20
   ```
2. **Запрос вывожу фотографии друзей**

   ```
   SELECT
     photos.user_id,
     photos.src
   FROM friends RIGHT OUTER JOIN photos ON friends.friend_id = photos.user_id
   WHERE friends.user_id = 1
   ORDER BY photos.id
   DESC LIMIT 20
   ```

**Таблица Друзей:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор пользователя',
  `friend_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор друга',
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `friend_id` (`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

**Таблица аудио записей:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Идентификатор аудиозаписи',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор пользователя',
  `src` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название mp3 файла',
  `artist` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Исполнитель',
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `artist` (`artist`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = 'Аудиозаписи' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;
```

**Таблица фотографий:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `src` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = 'Фотографии' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;
```

Comment: а зачем объединять в один?

Comment: Что значит "объединить" ? информация же разнородная. А как бы перемножение всех аудиозаписей на фотографии явно не к месту. И right очень странно тут смотрится, как будто вы хотите выбрать все аудиозаписи и если есть, то друзей к ним. left бы смотрелся явно более логично

Comment: короче - приведите как вы хотите увидеть информацию в результате

Comment: Что значит "объединить"  >>> я же написал это нужно для реализации новостной ленты, объединить значит следущее: что бы выводились и аудиозаписи и фотки единой лентой, по дате добавления как вконтакте общая лента новостей

Comment: и можно еще таблицу пользователей показать тут? Проще будет с запросом тогда

Comment: короче - приведите как вы хотите увидеть информацию в результате >>>

Ленту обновлений друзей пытаюсь вывести, что то типо:

Вася обновил аудиозапись 23.05.2015
Петя обновил фотографию 22.05.2015
Петя обновил аудиозапись 21.05.2015

Comment: @Alexandr для того чтоб выводилось единой лентой не обязательно объединять эти запросы, а чтоб выводилось по дате добавления необходимо эту дату откуда-то брать. у вас в таблицах я ее не вижу

Comment: Как аудиозаписи выбирать по дате, если у них нет даты. А когда дату найдете - делайте union этих двух запроов, дополнив NULL до одинакового кол-ва колонок и отсортируйте все вместе. Обратите внимание - надо сортировать именно по дате, по id не годится, т.к. они свои в каждой таблице

Comment: Возможно я что то не так понял, но чем ORDER BY audios.id отличается от если будет допустим ORDER BY audios.date ?

Comment: отличается тем, что в аудио добавили 1 запись, а в фото 10, причем первые 5 по времени до аудио, а 5 после. и как определить без времени добавления что аудиозапись должна быть между фото ?

Comment: Спасибо за разьяснение

Comment: Можно просто объеденить `photos` и `audios` и отфильтровать с подзапросом `where audio.user_id in(select id from frands where ... )`

Comment: Допустим я добавил в таблицу аудио дату, Но каким теперь образом слить их через union еще и по дате, не пойму я

Comment: По уму надо менять структуру базы данных. На текущей ничего путного не выйдет, как не старайся.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Добавить в таблицу аудио дату создания.
2. Написать запрос вида:

   ```
   SELECT audios.date as sort_date, audios.user_id, audios.src, audios.title,
          audios.artist,'audio' as type
     FROM friends JOIN audios ON friends.friend_id = audios.user_id
    WHERE friends.user_id = 1
   union all
   SELECT photos.date as sort_date, photos.user_id, photos.src, NULL title, NULL artist,  'photo' type
     FROM friends JOIN photos ON friends.friend_id = photos.user_id
    WHERE friends.user_id = 1
    ORDER BY sort_date desc
    LIMIT 20
   ```

В выборку я добавил поле `type` что бы программа делающая выборку сразу знала, что это за запись и как ее отображать. И убрал `right outer`, т.к. он тут вообще ни к чему

Для улучшения плана выполнения, возможно поможет такой запрос:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT audios.date as sort_date, audios.user_id, audios.src, audios.title,
              audios.artist,'audio' as type
         FROM friends JOIN audios ON friends.friend_id = audios.user_id
        WHERE friends.user_id = 1
        ORDER BY sort_date desc LIMIT 20
     ) A
    union all
    SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT photos.date as sort_date, photos.user_id, photos.src, NULL title, NULL artist,  'photo' type
         FROM friends JOIN photos ON friends.friend_id = photos.user_id
        WHERE friends.user_id = 1
        ORDER BY sort_date desc LIMIT 20
     ) A
     ORDER BY sort_date desc
     LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Да, этот вариант действительно рабочий, но EXPLAIN показывает страшные вещи: http://i.imgur.com/9vcwi2o.png

Comment: Вообщем ознакомился я с union и понял что он обходит всю таблицу и никакой limit, order by или индексы не спасают, предложите пожалуйста Ваши идеи реализации, как бы Вы вывели бы из база данное обновление друзей, большое заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так у ва индексы на user_id из audio и фото есть ? >> Выше же предоставил я таблицы все и там же видно что индексы есть!

Comment: заполнял таблицы данными, ситуация следующая если выводить запросы по отдельности и указывать order by и limit то всю таблицу не обходит а получает четко по индексу, если же соединять их через UNION то идет обход всей таблицы аудио и фото!

Comment: @Alexandr  так вы лимиты в каждый блок запроса пробовали ставить ? Я добавил в ответ пример запроса с лимитом на каждую таблицу

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам здесь distinct, тогда как данные в union'е из-за разного type гарантированно различаются? Здесь union all нужен. Кардинально ситуацию это не улучшит, просто частая ошибка писать union когда подразумевается union all.

Comment: union = union distinct via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: @Мелкий ok. поправил. Я изначально исходил из того, что данные всегда различаются и разницы не будет. и на план не влияло. дополнительной группировки ради дитинкта не появлялось

Comment: в любом случае union или union all это деоптимизированный вариант так как он обходит всю таблицу

Comment: <<< Для улучшения плана выполнения, возможно поможет такой запрос: если к запросу добавить EXPLAIN то мы увидим как работает запрос http://i.imgur.com/2luiJ7N.png он обходит всю таблицу!

Comment: Как объединить 2 запроса Вы ответили, на чем тема считаю закрыта, но задача по сути не решилась, видимо нужно менять алгоритм или структуру бд, подскажите пожалуйста Ваши идеи по этому поводу, но уже в этой теме http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498501/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-mysql всем спасибо!

Comment: аудитория 319 190 пользователей на данный момент, постов пока нет, только реализовывается этот функционал!