# Выборка обновлений друзей как вконтакте MySQL

Tags: mysql

### Всем доброго времени суток, помогите собрать запрос на вывод обновлений друзей как вконтакте!

Имеется следующая структура базы данных

**Таблица друзей:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор пользователя',
  `friend_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор друга',
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `friend_id` (`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

**Таблица аудиозаписей:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Идентификатор аудиозаписи',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Идентификатор пользователя',
  `src` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название mp3 файла',
  `artist` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Исполнитель',
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `artist` (`artist`,`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = 'Аудиозаписи' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;
```

**Таблица фотографий:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `src` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COMMENT = 'Фотографии' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 ;
```

[Тут создавал пост на объединение запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498119/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-mysql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5) но на практике union показал себя не оптимизировано, возможно у кого то есть другие предложения, например создать таблицу новостей или еще что то?

Comment: Кстати, вы не смотрели как подобные ленты работают. Ели у меня только 1 друг, он редко обновляет страницу и у него есть ровно 20 событий, за последние 3 года. В моей ленте новостей ходу выбираются все 20 событий. Хотя события произошедшие год назад как то на новости imho не тянут. Может нужно ограничение по датам ? Ели да - то на какую глубину

Answer (score 1):

Сравним чем отличаются таблицы аудиозаписей и фотографий: это только артист и название у аудио. Что у них общего: Поля user_id, date, src. Если копнуть чуть глубже то к ним могут появится лайки/дизлайки, комментарии, которые уже будут в других таблицах со ссылкой на данную.

Приходим к тому, что они слишком похожи и представляют собой одну сущность. По хорошему, все, что может быть в новостной ленте и на страницах пользователей - одна сущность. У вас еще нет просто текстовых сообщений ? могут появится. И тогда все резко становится на свои места. Пользователь пишет сообщение (или оставляет пустым или мы сообщение не предусматриваем) и к нему прикладывает фото или аудио. Исходя из этого можно предложить сделать одну таблицу, по структуре как текущее аудио. Добавить в нее еще "тип контента". И я бы задумался о вынесении артиста в отдельную таблицу и в "записях" только id артиста. При этом можно сделать автодополнение в поле с артистом и пользователю удобнее и у нас база более "чистая", меньше разных написаний одного и того же исполнителя.

А если посмотреть на какие нибудь соцсети, так выходит, что вообще есть сообщение и к нему могут быть несколько фото/аудио ... Это вы уже решайте, надо вам так или нет.

По поводу выборки последних новостей, я бы сделал единый индекс "user_id, date" и подумал бы о вопросе "глубины" истории, т.е. как минимум ограничить в where записи с датой больше текущая минус 3 месяца, например. Или вообще запоминать к пользователю (в БД или в кеше в памяти или вообще в куках), минимальную дату самой старой новости, которые ему уже показывались, тогда можно будет дополнительно ограничить выборку "не ранее" этой даты, т.к. мы знаем что с нее до сегодня точно было N записей (возможным удалением новостей пользователями предлагаю принибречь).

При подобных ограничениях по дате мы сильно упростим жизнь order by, ему придется сортировать гораздо меньше. У пользователей с большим кол-вом друзей и активным появлением новостей в его ленте вполне возможно, что первая страница новостей за последние два дня, если не меньше. И нам для ее выборки, если дату ранних новостей мы хранили, надо будет собственно найти и отсортировать записи только за 2-3 дня, а не за весь период существования системы.